# How to fix pandas merge function error while merging multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

I have several tab-separated files with the same first 2 columns. I am trying to merge these files side by side using pandas merge function.

I made a dataframe of all the files using glob and read_csv function. everything looks good till here. pandas merge function is throwing error out as below. pd concat works fine but that is not what I am looking for as it is adding new file below the current one. please help me with the usage.

```
  path = r'/data/tim/home/*' 
  file = glob.glob(path + "/sale.txt")
  df = (pd.read_csv(i,delimiter='\t') for i in files)

  #combine_df   = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
  combine_df   = pd.merge(df,on=1,2,how=outer")
```

my input files:

```
    table
    batch   date    code
       1    12/9    ghu
       3    12/19   gnu
       4    11/3    ghu

    table
    batch   date    quantity 
       1    12/9    20 
       3    12/19   54 
       4    11/3    37
```

required output:

```
    table
    batch   date    code  quantity
       1    12/9    ghu    20
       3    12/19   gnu    54
       4    11/3    ghu    37
```

I am getting this error. Since I already merged the files into single dataframe. How do I provide more than one argument?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combine_Sales.py", line 21, in <module>
    combine_df   = pd.merge(df,on=1,how=outer")
  TypeError: merge() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper instruction for two DataFrames is:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')
```

(you have to pass **both** merged DataFrames).

If you have more than 2 such DataFrames, you should:

- get first 2 of them and merge like above,
- then take the result and the next source DataFrame and merge
  them the same way.

**Alternative**:

If you have a list of DataFrames (*dfList*), you can perform a reduction,
using *functools.reduce*:

```
combined_df = functools.reduce(
    lambda dfA, dfB: pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='outer'),
    dfList[1:], dfList[0])
```

or even shorter:

```
combined_df = functools.reduce(
    lambda dfA, dfB: pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='outer'), dfList)
```

`how='outer'` is important if some DataFrames have "private" rows (which
don't occur in all other DataFrames).

And a hint concerning used variable names: *df* is usualy used for
a **single** DataFrame. Don't use it for a **list** of DataFrames.

## Edit

As I don't have your source files, I can't test it, but try:

- Create *dfList* as in your question `dFrames = (pd.read_csv(i, delimiter='\t') for i in files)`. Actually, it will be of *generator* type, not a *list*.
- Then call `functools.reduce(...)`, just as described earlier.

The advantage of this solution (assuming that it works) is that
each source DataFrame is created just before merging of it and then
garbage collected.

I confirmed validity of the above solution the following way:

- Created *df1*, *df2* and *df3*, from different source data.
- Created *dfL = (n for n in [df1, df2, df3])* (of *generator* type).
- Executed *functools.reduce(...)* for *dfL*.

The result was the same as for "ordinary" list of DataFrames.

Comment: Thank you I have several files to merge, hence I made a single dataframe of al the files before the merge command

Comment: If you have a **single** DataFrame, there is nothing to **merge**,
as this method requires just **two** DataFrames.
Probably you should create the source **list** of DataFrames calling
`dfList = [pd.read_csv(i, delimiter='\t') for i in files]` (expression
enclosed in square brackets, not parentheses).

Comment: can i use the source list and merge them side by side?

Comment: Yes, the merge is performed "horizontally" (i.e. side by side). Or try what I described in "Edit".

Comment: merge = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in all], axis=1) this fixed the issue.. thank you. ..but this merged all the columns from all the files. could you suggest how do i merge all columns from file 1 and only 2 columns from other files? Thanks!

Comment: *concat* is not a good solution, as it can be compared to "glueing together" printouts of all source DataFrames. So there is no way to avoid repetition of these two columns, which are merge columns.